# Controls cut off for narrow videos in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

When trying to embed a video that is narrower than about 200px the "full screen" control is cut off in Chrome. Safari and Firefox do not have this issue (well Firefox does but at least you can right-click and play full screen via a menu). Any way to force that control to appear Chrome? Here is example html:

```
<video width="200" controls>
    <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ba7kfp02/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which controls to show on HTML5 videos and when to show them is (unfortunately) open to interpretation by browser vendors.

If you absolutely need to have button that changes the video to "full screen", this is possible via JavaScript, using the [Full Screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode). Quoting from there, all the button has to do is call the following function (with some added boilerplate to care for browser support).

```
document.getElementById("myvideo").requestFullscreen();
```

If you need to have this button as an overlay of the video, you can remove the native controls (calling `removeAttribute("controls");` on the video element) and replace them with custom ones as demonstrated on the [Mozilla Japan video pages](http://www.mozilla.jp/videos/).

An interactive code example is on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/juGfk).